# $K(\ell_2)$ is separable?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators, separable-spaces

Please, help.
Why  $K(H)$, the space of compact operators on a separable Hilbert space $H$, is separable as a topological space? Particular, $H = \ell_2$?

Answer (score 1):

The finite-rank operators are dense in $K(H)$.  A finite-rank operator is a finite sum of operators of the form $x \mapsto \langle u, x \rangle v$ for $u, v \in H$.  Approximate $u$ and $v$ by members of a dense sequence in $H$.

Comment: Robert, and what is dense countable set in K(H)?